# How to make class sortable inside vector?

Tags: c++, class, vector, stl

I have a class say `class stuff{ int id; int ammount; int quality; /*...*/ };` and I have a `vector<stuff> items`. I want to make my collection sortable by `stuff::id` and searchable by `staff::id`. I could do it via find_if and sort using some sorting special stl lambda based function. Yet I want to have it all by default in vector. I heard there is some way to create hashing function yet I searched all around could not find it... So how to make class sortable/searchable inside vector with default vector functions?

Comment: Define `stuff::operator<(const stuff &that)` that returns `this->id < that.id`.

Comment: Could you use `std::map<int, int>` instead?

Comment: Point here is to get how to do such things as to be able to use my class also as `map` `pair::first`, to have search for all basic containers by class defined by my buisness logic - not general ints and strings.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For sorting, implement an `operator<` that compares two structures:

```
bool operator<(const stuff& s1, const stuff& s2)
{
    // Your comparison here
}
```

This is the operator that is used by default for most of all sorting.

For equality checking, create an `operator==` similarly.

Comment: I think the signature should be `bool operator<(const stuff& other)`, to compare `this` to `other`.

Comment: @gerowam Yes, if it's a *member* function. But not if it's a non-member function.